# Setting new values for a set of columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a case which should be solvable but my solution is too slow (hours slow):

I have a dataset in which, based on a condition I need to change the values of a some columns.

I wrote the code:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row.specific_column_value == 1:
        continue

    col_names = ['A1', 'A2', ..., 'An']
    new_values = [1, 2, 3, 4, .., n]

    for j, col in enumerate(col_names):
        df.loc[i, col] = new_values[j]
```

This is extremely slow.

How to speed it up?

Comment: By reading your code, I guess you should try removing the outer for loop once.. it just iterates over the rows ( unnecessarily )....

Answer (score 1):

You can do with `assign`the new value then `.loc` with your condition

```
df.loc[ df.order_received == 1, col_names ] = new_values
```

---

Update

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row.specific_column_value == 1:
        col_names = ['A1', 'A2', ..., 'An']
        new_values = [1, 2, 3, 4, .., n]
        df.loc[i, col_names ] = new_values
```

Comment: no the df_specific_column_value =1 can be true for many rows so i have to loop

Comment: @tstseby that is for multiple row...assignment , can you show us some sample data , or would like me you make one ? But it is better show us the expected output

Comment: @tstseby IIUC, the logic here is , if that row equal to 1 , you will assign newq value to those columns in that row , is that correct ?

Comment: I get ValueError: Incompatiable indexer with series -> I just need to replace the inner for loop with something faster -> I tried your solution with the df.specific_column_value replaced to index and I get the above error

Comment: thanks, it works ( i am sure i must hav tried it earlier) but it is still very slow, my data will take hours and hours any way to speed it up even more? does pandas have any faster operation for this.

Comment: @tstseby my oldest method `df.loc[ df.order_received == 1, col_names ] = new_values
`

Answer (score 0):

```
If you have limited number of columns(n), you may be able to reduced the search 
operation to O(n) instead of O(m x n) complexity that you have in current approach

inx_collection = set()
value_looking_for = 1
col_values = [1, 2, 3, 4, .., n]
for col in df.columns:
    inx = df.index[df[col] == value_looking_for]
    inx_collection.update(inx) # This set collects all indices containing the value
df.loc[inx_collection,:] = col_value
```

Comment: @tstseby, Does this help reduced your runtime?